# jQuery: assistance with updating div content onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div the contents of which constantly changes based on a server side process.  Currently I use jQuery load to poll the server every 3 seconds to get any updates.

This is what I have:

```
function poll() {
    reloadPage();
    setTimeout("poll();", 3000); 
}

function reloadPage() { 
      $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv>*", "");
}
```

This works well in firefox but in IE, the load doesn't update the div, probably due to a caching issue.  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do other than polling periodically?

Comment: what is `location.href + " #mydiv>*"` supposed to be?

Comment: It's doing a partial refresh on only that div

Comment: @Tomalak check the docs at http://api.jquery.com/load/, I had to look it up myself

Comment: `function reloadPage(){ $(..).load(.., function(){ setTimeout(reloadPage, 3000); }); reloadPage();` May I suggest that you write it like that instead? Just a humble suggestion :)

Comment: :) Since you're polling every 3 seconds, I'd suggest not using this method, but instead just fetching the necessary data. Will save you lots of processing and loading times.

Comment: @Znarkus: That depends on how complex the rest of the page is. Might be fairly simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the URL for each request to prevent IE from caching the response.

For example:

```
function poll() {
    reloadPage();
    setTimeout(poll, 3000); 
}

function reloadPage() { 
    $("#mydiv").load(location.href + "?Timestamp=" + new Date() + " #mydiv>*", "");
}
```

Also, you shouldn't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: jQuery doesn't cache responses without headers for caching? Just curious, e.g. PHP doesn't send these headers by default

Comment: @Znarkus: This is an IE issue; IE has very aggressive caching.

Comment: @Prabhu: It works, but it's bad practice.  (It's much slower)

Comment: @Prabhu: Passing the code as a string makes it eval it, which is something you should always avoid.
@SLaks: Thanks, good to know.

Comment: @Prabhu: Also see my answer for a shorter and more jQuery-style approach.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's ajax has a bunch of default settings, one of which controls caching.  If you set that to false it will append a timestamp to the ajax call to prevent caching.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: +1 for suggesting $.ajax. I never use the shorthands, this is just easier to remember.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do other than polling periodically?

Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, no. You have to poll to see what's going on on the server.

But there is a better way to implement the polling:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv>*", {Timestamp: new Date()});
}, 3000);
```

Notes:

- define an Interval instead of the Timeout,
- pass an actual function to `setInterval`, not a string
- use the `data` parameter of `load()` to pass in a cache breaker

Comment: Will setInterval start the first call after 3 seconds or will it start instantly?  I needed the first one to happen instantly.

Comment: @Prabhu: But the "first load" is the browser page load itself. Then the loads happen very three seconds. There is no need to refresh the page right after it finished loading.